# Why isn't my hello world node.js tcp server getting any connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I'm trying to test out Node.js and I'm using this code:

```
// Load the net, and sys modules to create a tcp server.
var net = require('net');
var sys = require('sys');

// Setup a tcp server
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

  // Every time someone connects, tell them hello and then close the connection.
  socket.addListener("connect", function () {
    //sys.puts("Connection from " + socket.remoteAddress);
    console.log("Person connected.");

    var myPacket = [1,2,3,4,5];
    sys.puts(myPacket);
    socket.end("Hello World\n");
  });

});

// Fire up the server bound to port 7000 on localhost
server.listen(7000, "localhost");

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("TCP server listening on port 7000 at localhost.");
```

To send a byte array to any connections that show up on port 7000 of local host. Nothing is connecting though, I've tried firefox (localhost:7000, and 127.0.0.1:7000) I tried PuTTy, and even writing my own Java TCP Client to connect to local host, but nothing is working, so I'm convinced that the code is wrong.

Can someone please tell me why my code won't allow connections?

Comment: I added while(true){} after console.log, and got the same results :(

Comment: just read the manual, e.g. there's error handling

Comment: Read the manual is a stupid thing to say on a website about answering programming questions. Just saying.

Comment: And why is that so? I fail to see the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating the connection part. The callback with the socket is already the connection event so you don't need to listen to it separately. Also, if you want to send binary, use the [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) class. Here's your code changed. Remember to set your mode to telnet in putty when connecting. I've also changed the end() to write() so it doesn't auto close the connection.

```
// Load the net, and sys modules to create a tcp server.
var net = require('net');
var sys = require('sys');

// Setup a tcp server
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    //sys.puts("Connection from " + socket.remoteAddress);
    console.log("Person connected.");

    var myPacket = new Buffer([65,66,67,68]);
    socket.write(myPacket);
    socket.write("Hello World\n");

});

// Fire up the server bound to port 7000 on localhost
server.listen(7000, "localhost");

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("TCP server listening on port 7000 at localhost.");
```